# re in python matches the to-be-matches-substring and anything that comes after it

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex such that it matches any string with some initial Letters, spaces or comma followed by the string '[edit]'. This is the code that i have written:

```
if re.match(r'[A-Za-z ,]+\[edit\]', value):
    print('ha')
else:
    print('na')
```

It does not give false negatives, that is it matches string 'banana[edit]   but it also matches for 'banana[edit]a'. As i understand it re stops evaluating when it finds the desired substring and returns a match, when it is not so.

How can I write the regex so that it does not match any strings of the type 'banana[edit]a'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
if re.match(r'[A-Za-z ,]+\[edit\]$', value):
                                 ^
```

Here, `$` is to indicate end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want characters after your expression to cause it not to match, simply specify that that's the end of the string with the special `$` character:

```
if re.match(r'[A-Za-z ,]+\[edit\]$', ...
```